# Issue in Use alias names for a column in sql and deploy it in Tomcat

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat8.5

I am working on a web application which uses Oracle as a Database and deploying the app into Tomcat8. When I use an alias for a column name, the fetching of the records using alias is giving an error like below:
unexpected error: SQL exception while accessing[alias for Column] : Invalid Column:

The below is the query:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName buyerName, Orders.OrderID OID
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```

This query is working without unsg alias buyerName and OID while deploying into Tomcat server.

Could any one throw some light on this Issue?

Comment: You need to show us the Java code as well.  As raw SQL, no, there is nothing wrong with your query.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Biegeleisen, I am using while(resultSet.next()){ resultSet.getString('buyerName') }

Comment: If that is your literal code, then yes it would throw an error, because you are surrounding `buyerName` in single quotes, when it needs double quotes.  When I asked for you code, I meant include all relevant Java code in your actual question, not as a cryptic comment.

Comment: Sorry, That is double quotes, not single quote, this code is working in another container(Jetty), Now I  will not be able to show the code here